# How to present number of likes from several facebook like buttons?

Tags: facebook, asp-classic, facebook-like

I have like buttons in each of my website pages.
Each specifies the page url, e.g. href=http://www.efratnakash.com/about_website_e.asp

How can I present the sum of all likes in my website?
Something like: href=http://www.efratnakash.com/*.asp

Thanks,

Efrat

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to generate the required Script and Html tags using [the official Facebook page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/)

You'll end up with the following code to insert at the top of your page:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and the following snippet to insert where you want your 'Likes' count:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.efratnakash.com/" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

I'm not sure if this would give you the sum of **all** of the likes for your domain though. If you need a more powerful way to query your likes data, you might want to look into using [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/), part of the [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api), where you could perform queries like:

[SELECT total_count FROM link_stat WHERE url = http://www.efratnakash.com](https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20total_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url=%27http://www.efratnakash.com%27)

Giving you the following JSON data:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "total_count": 12
      }
   ]
}
```

(I must admit, this is my first go with FQL though!) Does 12 sound like the total number of your likes, or just ones on your homepage? If it's too low, I'm sure there must be some way to sum all likes for that domain.

Hope this is of some use!